# SoundPool not playing sound

Tags: android, soundpool

I am trying to play a sound in my activity using `SoundPool` but I am unable to hear the sound.

```
private void beginGame(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash1);

       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
           AudioAttributes aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                   .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                   .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                   .build();


           sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
                   .setMaxStreams(10)
                   .setAudioAttributes(aa)
                   .build();
       }else{
           sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);
       }

        sid = sp.load(Splash1.this,R.raw.bubble,1);
        sp.play(sid,1,1,1,0,0.99f);

        Thread loading = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                    // TODO NEXT ACTIVITY
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        loading.start();
    }
```

Comment: Is the app executing without errors or does it crash?

Comment: no there are no errors

Comment: which API level do you use for testing?

Comment: Im testing on API 19 KitKat

Comment: You are calling `play()` right after `load()`. The loading operation takes a while and instead you could/should use an [OnLoadCompleteListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html) to know when the sound can actually be played back. There's already an example of that in Jerry's answer.

Comment: i think that may be the problem let me try

Comment: thanks @MarkusKauppinen its solved now i was missing the listener :)

Answer (score 2):

Initially, in a project i worked on, i had a class like [AnswerSound] the one below, so i always get instance of it and call any method as i need. I hope you can look at at and kick of from it.

```
public class AnswerSound {
private final float volume;
private Context context;

private SoundPool correctAnswerSoundPool;
private int correctAnswerSoundID;
boolean correctLoaded = false;


private SoundPool wrongAnswerSoundPool;
private int wrongAnswerSoundID;
boolean wrongLoaded = false;
public AnswerSound(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    correctAnswerSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10);
    correctAnswerSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener(){
    @Override
       public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
      correctLoaded = true;
                         }
          }
    );

    wrongAnswerSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10);

    wrongAnswerSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener()
     {
     @Override
     public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
      wrongLoaded = true;
        }
       }

    );
    //assign the sound IDS
    correctAnswerSoundID = correctAnswerSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.correct_answer, 1);

    wrongAnswerSoundID = wrongAnswerSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.wrong_answer_sound_effect, 2);

    //getting the user sound settings
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

    //then you can play the sound by checking if the sound is loaded
}



public void playCorrectAnswerSound()
{
    if (correctLoaded) {
        correctAnswerSoundPool.play(correctAnswerSoundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

}
public void playWrongAnswerSound() {
    if (wrongLoaded) {
        wrongAnswerSoundPool.play(wrongAnswerSoundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}
```

}